# What exactly is a "sleeping" dyno

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

This question actually means a couple of things.
First of all I want to ask what exactly happens when a dyno sleeps?

- If I have global variables stored in an array in my bot, does it get
  wiped when it sleeps (so that means that I have to actually save
  everything to external files)? - Basically does my memory data cleared
  when it sleeps, when it wokes up my bot won't be having that data?
- Secondly, for the 550 free dyno hours, can I schedule a sleeping
  schedule (e.g., 01:00 - 7:00 am) or is it not a daily limit (18h/day)
  but a monthly limit (so a 24/7 uses up the hours until I have 0 for
  the rest of the month)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding on to what @Beppe C said in his answer, in order to understand dyno sleeping, you need to understand the difference between web and worker dynos.

Web dynos allow you to show a webpage, some file content, etc. This dyno goes to sleep periodically (after 30 minutes of inactivity). This is where you're getting the phrase dyno sleeping. If you insist on using a web dyno (as in you need to show content), the best way to schedule it is by using the Heruko Scheduler add-on. However, I don't recommend this, as it requires you to enter your credit card information. Otherwise, you could use a cron job service.

Worker dynos are different. As long as you don't use up your 550 hours in a given month (the hour limit is monthly), they will stay running without sleeping. With a worker dyno, any global variables will be saved for the duration of the time that the process stays running, unless you stop the process. The downside is that they work in the background, meaning that you can't show/display web content with them. If you need to show web content, stick with a web dyno.

To start a worker process for an app, scale up the app like so:

```
# scale up
heroku ps:scale worker=1 -a {appname}
```

Read more documentation about worker dynos here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing

My advice? If you don't need to show web content, use a worker dyno that periodically shuts off at a given time every day. Since you seem to be using node.js, maybe use setInterval to check the time?

Comment: thank you for your answer! It clears up a lot. So if I use Heroku for a Discord bot (that only runs commands in Discord and therefore not host web content), it would only use worker dynos. Automated shutdown sounds handy to limit dyno hours used, but unfortunately that still sounds like I have to manually start it up, which is impractical. If that is the case, I will either have to link a creditcard that I don't have or look for a different provider.

Comment: Yeah. You aren't hosting web content, so use worker dynos. Confirming what you said, you need to add a credit card to set up automated shutdown (the Heroku Scheduler addon). So really your only two options if you want to use Heroku: find a way to programmatically check the time with the discord program or remember to shut it off manually every day. Otherwise, you might need to find a different provider. Hopefully that clears everything up

Answer (score 0):

A sleeping dyno is when the virtual node shuts down stopping the application which runs on it. The application memory is cleared (yes, all your variables and arrays) and it cannot process any request until the dyno restarts.
Any data which needs to survive should be persisted to an external storage (external file system, database).

A Web dyno goes to sleep after 30 min inactivity (ie no http requests have arrived), you cannot schedule this.
A Worker does not go to sleep and it runs until your free quota has run out.

You can always scale down (shutdown) and scale up (restart) using the command line.

```
 # scale down
 heroku ps:scale web=0 -a {appname}
```